# Repeated error in logs: MaxListenersExceededWarning

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having issues figuring out why I keep getting the following error:

MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 wakeup listeners added to [Connection]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

Below is my code:

```
export const Mychatapp = () => {

  var connnections = {}

  const WebSocket = require('ws');

  const webSocketServer = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8443 });

  console.log("Websocket listening on 8443")

  webSocketServer.on('connection', (webSocket) => {

    webSocket.on('message', (message) => {

      var newdata = JSON.parse(message)

      switch (newdata.command) {

        case "connect":

          connnections[newdata.data.id] = webSocket;

          break;

        case "message":
         
          let msgsent = chatService.sendmsg(newdata.data);

          if (connnections[newdata.data.to_id]) {

            connnections[newdata.data.to_id].send(message);

            if (msgsent.success) {
              connnections[newdata.data.toid].send(message);
            }

            chatService.pushsend(newdata.data);

          } else {

            chatService.pushsend(newdata.data);

     
          }
          break;
        default:

      }
    });

  });

}
```

I am not sure what to do. Please assist.

Tried using once instead of .on. Very stuck as to what to try.